# Independant Variable for Function when called Multiple Times

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables, if-statement, element

I'm trying to create a function that will print an element in a list. However, I want it so I can print the next element every time the function is utilized in an If Statement. Here's what I got:

```
import random

index = 0
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', ]
list2 = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco', ]

def reshuffle(list):
    global index
    if index < len(list):
        print(list[index])
        index += 1
    elif index == len(list):
        random.shuffle(list)
        index = 0
        print(list[index])
        index += 1

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter command: ")
    if user_input == "e":
        print(reshuffle(list=list1))
    if user_input == "s":
        print(reshuffle(list=list2))
```

What happens is whenever the function prints off all the elements in the list with the if statement, it shuffles them and starts over. It does this by using index, but each time the function is used by more than one if statement, it reads off the same variable. The output looks like this:

```
Enter command: e
one
None
Enter command: e
two
None
Enter command: s
tres
None
Enter command: s
cuatro
None
```

I want it to do this:

```
Enter command: e
one
None
Enter command: e
two
None
Enter command: s
uno
None
Enter command: s
dos
None
```

How can I have each function call use the same variable independently, without resetting the variable? Or if there's another way to approach this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? You are comparing list length to the index, however only call list1 twice. also you are shuffling list2 before printing so its order is nondeterministic .

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make it so I can randomize a list of strings once all items in a list are printed. I'm using this approach to prevent using a random.choice, since that can choose the same item 3 times in a row and such. I don't want that, so this is my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lists share the same global `index`, so an index change for one list naturally affects the other.

You should create a subclass of `list` with `index` as an instance variable, make `reshuffle` a method of the class, and make `list1` and `list2` instances of that class, so that they can each keep track their own indices:

```
import random

class List(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.index = 0

    def reshuffle(self):
        if self.index < len(self):
            print(self[self.index])
            self.index += 1
        elif self.index == len(self):
            random.shuffle(self)
            self.index = 0
            print(self[self.index])
            self.index += 1

list1 = List(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'])
list2 = List(['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco'])

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter command: ")
    if user_input == "e":
        print(list1.reshuffle())
    if user_input == "s":
        print(list2.reshuffle())
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter command: e
one
None
Enter command: e
two
None
Enter command: s
uno
None
Enter command: s
dos
None
```

Comment: I do have a question. If I remove the print statements in reshuffle, why does it keep returning None when print(list1.reshuffle()) executes? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Use a return statement that subtracts one from index. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it! :-)